# How to pass Table(list of numbers) from Lua to C and access it

Tags: c++, c, lua

I want to pass a list containing numbers from Lua to C and access it in C. How can I do it?

Suppose I have the following Table:

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6}
```

I want to send it to C and store this table in array in C.

I sent it using:

```
quicksort(x)
```

where `quicksort` is the function I have defined in C.

How can I access the `x` in C?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The table you pass to the function will be on the function's stack. You can index it by using `lua_getfield` or `lua_gettable`.

Traversing the table with [`lua_next`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_next), you can populate your array in C if you need to; although, for an array, simply iterating from 1 to `#t` should suffice.

Some example utility code (untested):

```
int* checkarray_double(lua_State *L, int narg, int *len_out) {
    luaL_checktype(L, narg, LUA_TTABLE);

    int len = lua_objlen(L, narg);
    *len_out = len;
    double *buff = (double*)malloc(len*sizeof(double));

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        lua_pushinteger(L, i+1);
        lua_gettable(L, -2);
        if(lua_isnumber(L, -1)) {
            buff[i] = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
        } else {
            lua_pushfstring(L,
                strcat(
                    strcat(
                        "invalid entry #%d in array argument #%d (expected number, got ",
                        luaL_typename(L, -1)
                    ),
                    ")"
                ),
                i, narg
            );
            lua_error(L);
        }
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    return buff;
}
```

Comment: I haven't touched C, nor the Lua C API, for a looonngg time; if I've made any mistakes in the code, could someone please correct them.

Comment: Thanks Deco and jpjacobs for your kind help, but I have a doubt... Since on passing the virtual stack to the C program, how can I receive it? If I want to use lua_gettable, then what should be my index value?? I am unsure what to use for index value. I have just passed a table x from the lua program to C. I don't know its length, which I can get by lua_gettop but what index should I use in lua_gettable and I should store this table in what type of variable. I am having some doubts in it. Sorry I am new to Lua, so please bear with me. And thanks for your help Again..... :)

Comment: Can you provide me a link of some good site where the "Lua" stack push and pop operations are explained. I am unable to get why we have done here lua_pop(L,1). I tried it and  it worked with this, but I think to pop an element from stack, we need to pop out the top, so here it should have been lua_pop(L,-1). But why is it "1". Rest my code has started working, got the concept of stack index at top and then using lua_gettable, but couldn't get why we are using index for pop as 1. Can you throw some light on this topic? It would be helpful for all.

Comment: The table you pass sits on the stack, it *is* not stack by itself. A good place to look is the authoritative guide: [Programming in Lua, Part IV](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.html)

Comment: The index at gettable should be -2-i, and not -2 :)

Comment: @DanielSevero I don't think so: -2 is the stack index of the table that is to be indexed by the integer pushed to the top of the stack in the line before. see [lua_gettable in the reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_gettable)